# Outlier detection using outlierTest function

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, outliers

I found an outlier using the `outlierTest` function in the car package. However, I can see from the results that the Externally Studentized Residual and p-values.
This is a result.

[image]

This indicates that the 718th observation has an outlier. right??

The code to derive the result is as follows.

```
credit<-read.csv("german.csv", header = TRUE)

F=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
for(i in F) credit[,i]=as.factor(credit[,i])

german_logit<-glm(Creditability~.,data=credit, family = "binomial")
library("car")
german_outlier<-outlierTest(german_logit,n.max=9999)
german_outlier
```

If so, is it correct to delete the 718th observation?

I want to know what variable has outlier and its value, because I want to change that value as proper value. What function do I have to use?

Answer (score 2):

So few points of clarity:

What do you mean by an outlier? Here observation 718 is such that its dependent variable in the `glm` model has an unusual value based on its independent variables. If you look at the dataset in a different way i.e. using say bivariate analysis on another variable, the same observation or may not get flagged as an outlier.

To display data values use `credit[718,]` for more information on subsetting use `?'['` in console to pull up the help page.

You're passing all variables to the model using formula `Creditability ~.` so your outlier will be a row, and not a single variable.

Now onto deleting observations, it is advised to instead create a column or a list as an indicator of outliers / outlier row numbers. In such a way, you can subset your data set according and you never lose data.

Comment: I can't understand that creating a cloumn or a list as an indicator of outliers. 718 is not variable. it is an observation. I want to know that what independent variable has outlier. So I will change the outlier value as other value. But If i use outlierTest function, I can know just what observation has outlier not variable.

Comment: You should be **very wary** of changing your data! outlier detection is meant to flag observations that **might** be in error, so you can investigate them. It is not a license to change the data. An outlier could very well be a legitimate observation.

Answer (score 2):

Read the result of `outlierTest()` again.

It found *zero* outliers as it says "No Studentized residuals with Bonferonni p < 0.05"

It then lists the largest studentized residual it **DID** find, which happens to be at row 718.

The function is not saying that 718 is an outlier; rather, it is saying that it *did not find any outliers*. Observation 718 is merely the largest studentised residual. That is to say, 718 is the closest thing to an outlier it has found. However, since the Bonferroni Correction has a minimum value of around 3.51 at n=23, the value of -2.888274 for row 718 is still not close to being considered an outlier under this threshold.

Regardless, *do not delete data points just because they do not fit your model, and you really want your model to be correct.*

- You must have a good, objective reason for deleting data points.
- If you delete any data after you've collected it, justify and
  describe it in your reports.
- If you are not sure what to do about a data point, analyze the data
  twice — once with and once without the data point — and report the
  results of both analyses.

There's a famous story that the hole in the Ozone layer over Antarctica would have been discovered a decade earlier had [outliers collected via satellite not been automatically discarded.](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/omitting-outliers/)